Measure of a set defined by another set
Let $S$ be a subset of $[0,1]²$ with the (2-dim lebesgue) measure $1-c$. Then we define the set $X$ to be all $k$ tupels where the entries are pairwise in $S$. Now I want a lower bound on the ((k-2)-dimensional lebesgue) measure of $X$.
I basically want to show that for small $c$ the measure of $X$ is also greater than $1-c$.
I tried it with probability but I am a little confused. Let's pick k distinct $x_1,...,x_k$ in $[0,1]$. I defined the indicator random variable $A_{i,j}$ which is 1 if $(x_i,x_j) \in S$ and $0$ else. So the measure of $\lambda(X)$ should be $\mathbb{P}(\prod_{i\neq j \in [[k]]} A_{i,j}=1) = 1- \mathbb{P}(\prod_{i\neq j \in [[k]]} A_{i,j}=0) \geq 1-c$ since $\mathbb{P}(\prod_{i\neq j \in [[k]]} A_{i,j}=0) \leq c$ because the probability that one of the indicator random variables is 0 is smaller than c or do I have to multiply by $\binom{k}{2}$ or am I on the completely wrong track?
Help would be much appreciated.
